# How assign permission to user in mogodb

Tags: mongodb

I created a new database in mongodB and a user for this db, but when the user is connected,  he can see the others databases.

How can Limit the access to database ?

I want the user can only connect to a single database

I use this query for user creation:

create new user

`db.createUser({user:'userA',pwd:'userA.server.2018',roles:[{role:'readWrite',db:'haip-db'}]})`

Comment: Do you have Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) enabled? By default, it is not.

Comment: Oh no! , I will try enable this.